# Membership Pay later and Activity Renewal

Tags: civimember, activities, renewals

I don't understand why, for a first membership, when a member chooses the "Pay later" option s.he gets a new activity "Renewal" recorded once the payment is manually added by the admin but not if s.he just pays live with credit card?

It's not a renewal and I don't want this activity to be added. This is mistaking the reports for those who are really renewing their membership and need to be separately identified for backoffice purpose.

I don't have a special CiviRule that would involve this behaviour so I guess it's build in CiviCRM.

I'm using CiviCRM 5.21.0 on Drupal 7.67

How could I fix this?

regards,
Guillaume

EDIT 1:
Activity Renewal is "Renouvellement d'adhésion". It comes automatically every time I use the pay later option. I don't get :-/
[image]

EDIT 2:
I've tried on a different CiviCRM/Drupal website and it ends the same. It creates an unwanted Renewal activity

EDIT 3: After a step-by-step comparison with the demo, it appears that when registering a member, CiviCRM creates an "Online or offline membership signup." activity that I don't see on the demo instead it creates a Pending membership coloured in red that is deleted after a payment. And when entering a contribution, it logically adds a "Renewal" activity. So now, it's more about why is CiviCRM creating this first membership and no more why I get a renewal activity. little step forward...

Comment: Hi Guillaume! I've tried to replicate this on 5.21 and in my instance Civi does record the contribution and membership as pending (pay later)/pending respectively and the activity for membership sign up updates from 'scheduled' to 'completed' for a new membership. If you can it may be worth replicating on the Civi demo to establish if it's configuration related after all?

Comment: Thanks Rebecca for trying ans for the tip! I'll test on the demo.

Comment: it seems to obvious to mention but make sure you do not click on 'renew' when you record the payment, just use Edit option on the Membership or Contribution tabs

Comment: As above. I would encourage to use the 'record payment' via the contribution rather than via the membership as that's the actual financial transaction associated with that membership.

Comment: I'm doing it through the Contribution tab ;-)

Answer (score 3):

On the demo site I took the following route and saw no issues

- change the Contrib page to accept Pay Later
- completed a Pay Later membership for the demo user
- confirmed that by then clicking on Edit for membership at backend, clicking on the Contribution block with 'more' and 'record payment' the membership was set to Current and there was no 'renewal' Activity on their record.

Hope that helps

Data will be on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=203 for less than 12 hours till it is flushed.

Comment: thanks Pete. Actually it works and behaves the way it should and I need. I have to check my process :-/

Comment: I'm having the same behaviour on the same site with a test webform and I can't find where to set this :-/ Where could this be set within CiviCRM?

Comment: it does the same as on the demo plus adding a renewal. And it comes to the same point by either using the webform or from the backoffice. I'm a bit turning mad.

Comment: i can't think why a renewal would be added unless you have something 'extra' doing this on purpose eg CiviRules, extension, etc

Comment: I'm checking every single extension and rule and this is really weird :-/

Comment: when you say 'test webform' i am not certain if you mean a Drupal webform using webform_civicrm or just a civi form? my testing on dmaster was just using civicrm contribution page, not a Webform

Comment: I face unfortunately exactly the same situation using either a classic CiviCRM contribution page or a webform

Comment: so you get your problem with both Drupal webforms and also with standard civicrm contribution forms

Comment: yes and on different versions especially on our sandbox without any active extension :-/

Comment: I really think this is a bug because on a brand new Drupal 7.72 - CiviCRM 5.25 I have the same situation. It creates automatically a "Membership renewal" activity :-(

Comment: I just repeated steps above on dmaster.demo (with slight variation as how one records payment has changed slightly) - I still get no Renewal Activity created.

Comment: I can't understand what happens :-/

Comment: what could induce such a behaviour? Is there a basic parameter to set in CiviCRM?