# Manually add Membership Renewal Activity

Tags: activity

For one client I have a member who anticipated his renewal and for a reason I don't understand, CiviCRM didn't add a 'membership renewal' activity. Because I have rules triggered by this new activity I need to manually add it. I know how to manually remove but is there a way to manually add this activity. I only found Meeting and Phone call.

Any ideas

regards,

Guillaume

Comment: You created a custom Activity Type? and you set it to be used on Contacts? and you now want to manually add one such Activity to a Contact? But that Activity Type does not show either on the Contact's Action button or on their Activity Tab?

Comment: I have no custom activity. It's a normal renewal and doesn't appear to be identify this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API Explorer to do this (**Support menu » Developer » APIv3 Explorer**) but this isn't recommended unless you can test it first on a test site.  Select **Activity** as your entity and **Create** as your action, you should be able to pick any Activity Type from there.

It's also worth trying to figure out why the activity wasn't created to begin with, otherwise it may happen again.

Comment: I changed the way I manipulate contacts and anyway it's a strange behavior. Is there a way to change the settings of the "membership renewal" activity? I have an issue with this kind of activity: either it creates an unnecessary activity (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35594/membership-pay-later-and-activity-renewal?) or it doesn't create a necessary activiy (this post).